# How to export a linear regression formula out of sklearn LinearRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I want to have the formula of the model in order to use it in other languages/projects. Is there a way to export the formula from the model?

I will use [sklearn linear regression model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

What I want to do eventually: given a formula f(), and data set 'd', I will have java script code that will give me predictions on d based on f().

Comment: Searching for "javascript linear regression" gives plenty of hits for direct implementations in js. I'd go that way, instead of trying to go through Python.

Comment: linear regression fits the weights for a linear combination. All you have to do is to extract those.

Answer (score 13):

The formula can be described essentially by the learned coefficients. The coefficients can be obtained using the attributes `coef_` and `intercept_`. The dot product between the coefficients and the input vector plus the intercept gives the output of the model.

The actual code that implements this "formula" in scikit-learn is something like:

```
return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
                       dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
```

which should not be too difficult for you to port over to your other project.